# C# Entity Framework - Invalid column name

Tags: c#, entity-framework, console

I have a Context with these two classes:

In the Brand class, there's a Bike objects list.

When I try to put the Bike list in an instance of Brand, the program returns me this exception:

```
Invalid column name 'Strokes'.
Invalid column name 'BrandBike_BrandID'.
```

This is my context:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Brand> Brands{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<Bike> Bikes{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

This is my class named Brand:

```
public class Brand
{
    [Key]
    public int BrandID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Country Nationality { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Bike> Models { get; set; }
}

public class Bike
{
    [Key]
    public int BikeID { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }
    public BikeCategory Category { get; set; }
    public int EngineCapacity { get; set; }
    public int Strokes { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }

    public virtual Brand BrandBike { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Brand table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Brands] (
[BrandID]     INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Nationality] INT            NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Brands] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BrandID] ASC)
);
```

And this the Bike table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bikes] (
[BikeID]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Model]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Category]      INT            NOT NULL,
[EngineCapacity]    INT            NOT NULL,
[Price]        FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL,
[Brand_BrandID] INT            NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Bikes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([BikeID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Bikes_dbo.Brands_Brand_BrandID] FOREIGN KEY 
([Brand_BrandID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Brands] ([BrandID])
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Brand_BrandID]
ON [dbo].[Bikes]([Brand_BrandID] ASC);
```

How can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Show your table's structure

Comment: Add that to the question with proper formatting, so that everyone can read it more easily

Comment: Ok, I added it to the question

Comment: Please specify the `Bike` table structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the *"Invalid column name 'BrandBike_BrandID'"* error, you need to add a column named `BrandId` to your table `Bike`. This Column should store the `BrandId` that the Bike is related to.

I do not have your `Bike` table structure, but the *"Invalid column name 'Strokes'"* indicates that there is no column named `Strokes` in that table.

Comment: Ok, there are no the two columns, how do I add them?

Comment: As far as I can see, `Bikes` has a column named `Brand_BrandID` that refers to the related `Brand`. You need to add this property to you `Bike` model.

Comment: I used [this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx) to update the database. Thank you very much.